# How to deal with "Failed to connect to repository: git.exe ls-remote -h git@github.com:" error?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have added a "Deploy keys" on github (The 'Key' I got from my aws .pem file). Also I was trying to create a new one in my aws console.

I'm trying to connect with 'git@github.com:somename.git' link, but 'https://github.com/somename/.git' also does not work.

The question is: What I'm doing wrong?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Have yu generates ssh key? not a pem file but ssh. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Comment: i'm using windows, so i've tried to open my pem file (from aws) in PuTTYgen and then got ssh-rsa key, after that i added it in github deploy keys, is it ok?

Comment: Does your security group allow port 22 out for GitHub?